# Auto-complete on TeXstudio

Tags: texstudio

I am using TeXstudio. When using the auto-complete function (hint) in my language (Vietnamese), the command will automatically be complete in Vietnamese, e.g.  `\Leftrightarrow` will become `\Lè`. Also, the auto-complete function `\Leftrightarrow` doesn't work sometimes. How to fix this?

I tried to force `\Leftrightarrow` to become `\Lè` and vice versa, but it did not work.

Comment: try setting the language to `en` in `Options -> Configure TeXstudio -> General -> Language -> <choose EN from dropdown menu>`

Comment: I have tried but it's failed!
I think it's related to Unikey but I can't change it